# Condition function on counting and summation of values of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-datareader

I have a data frame including "Altitude" and "Distance" variables. I would calculate the "Slope" variable using these two mentioned variables.
I want to put a condition function to start from the top column of the "Distance" variable and add up (sum) values until the summation of them is greater or equal to 10 (>=10). If this condition corrects then calculate the "Slope" using the given formula: Slope=Average(Altitude(from the first value to the index that the distance has stopped there). Please see the figure below. It might make better sense than how I am looking for the Slope calculation. I would appreciate any help with it. I tried the command serries below but obviously, it doesn't work.

```
s=[]
for i in list(range(df.shape[0])):
    if sum(df.loc[i,'Distance']) < 10:
       k=sum(df.loc[i,'Distance'])
    elif sum(df.loc[i,'Distance']) > 10:
        KM_mean=sum(df.loc[i,'Distance'])/len(df.loc[i,'Distance'])
        s.append(KM_mean)
Slope=Average('Altitude')/sum('Distance')

Altitude  Distance
11.2      0
11.2      3.018
10.9      4.18
10.1      4.873
9.9       5.499
9.4       5.923
9.2       6.415
8.5       1.063
8.4       1.667
7.9       3.114
```

[image]

Comment: please post the data, not an image.

Comment: And fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: in the original code compiler the indents are correct but I think the code is written in a wrong way

Comment: @JonathanLeon I have added the data now

Comment: You're not using the altitude at all.

Comment: i couldn't continue on completing the code because of that I put the figure to show what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to track the accumulated sum yourself.  Your use of the `sum` function is only summing the current row.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
[11.2,     0],
[11.2,     3.018],
[10.9,     4.18],
[10.1,     4.873],
[9.9 ,     5.499],
[9.4 ,     5.923],
[9.2 ,     6.415],
[8.5 ,     1.063],
[8.4 ,     1.667],
[7.9 ,     3.114]
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['Altitude','Distance'])
print( df )

s=[]
sumdist = 0
sumalt = 0
cntx = 0
for i in list(range(df.shape[0])):
    sumdist += df.loc[i,'Distance']
    sumalt += df.loc[i,'Altitude']
    cntx += 1
    if sumdist >= 10:
        KM_mean = sumalt / cntx / sumdist
        s.append(KM_mean)
        sumdist = sumalt = 0
        cntx = 0
if cntx:
    s.append( sumalt / cntx / sumdist )
print(s)
```

Output:

```
   Altitude  Distance
0      11.2     0.000
1      11.2     3.018
2      10.9     4.180
3      10.1     4.873
4       9.9     5.499
5       9.4     5.923
6       9.2     6.415
7       8.5     1.063
8       8.4     1.667
9       7.9     3.114
[0.8988484798276862, 0.8448607949571003, 0.6933681376947548]
```

I suppose you could track the start of the current region and use `df.sum` over and over, but that seems like a waste.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the first version like yours, just summing the distances in "sumx" before I re-read the requirement and realized you were supposed to be summing altitudes as well.  You should have been able to figure that out from my code, but I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. The results that I got "s" a list of numbers 1 to zero. it is not following the Slope formula that I have written in the question box.   1.0866517655056398
0.8367798722129431
0.5635030354030174
0.40013703416387025
0.30762053642601644
0.22991485468515618
0.18818492592145195
0.14976098904432017
0.12609377341741507
0.10472003447848958
0.09372822468920775
0.08187638982116632
0.07672113210527
0.07067390870061778
0.06392673484772572

Comment: You have three chunks where the distance is greater than 10.  The answers for those three chunks are [0.8988484798276862, 0.8448607949571003, 0.6933681376947548].  If you aren't expecting exactly three answers (m:n, n:k, k:p), then you have not specified the question correctly.  Where does 1.08665 come from?

Comment: Thanks so much Tim, it works now. I was wondering to ask you another question and would be grateful if you could answer. The next step is just repeating the received number from the code: [0.8988484798276862, 0.8448607949571003, 0.6933681376947548]. I am looking to repeat each figure by the number of rows associated with it. for example, 0.8988484798276862 will be repeated four times in a new column then 0.8448607949571003 will be repeated two times and so on

Comment: You should be able to figure this out.  You have the number of rows that matched in `cntx`.  So, do `s.extend( [KM_mean] * cntx )`, and a similar thing with the final append.